# mypy call-arg error where default argument is set

Tags: python, python-decorators, type-hinting, mypy

I have code that looks like the following:

```
from typing import Callable


def decorate(func: Callable[[str], None]) -> Callable[[str], None]:
    return func


@decorate
def do_something(some_str: str = 'Hello world') -> None:
    print(some_str)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_something()
```

When running mypy, it reports the following error for the last line:

> error: Too few arguments for "do_something"  [call-arg]

How can I fix this error (without changing the return type of `decorate` to `Callable[..., None]`)?

Comment: Good question. The problem is that `mypy` doesn't know that `decorate` returns a function that has a default value; the fact that `decorate` returns its argument is a *dynamic* property of the decorator, not a *static* property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TypeVar` to indicate that the input and return type are *equivalent* and defined by the `Callable` received. Since `Callable` types include the entire signature, this lets the type checker infer positional/optional/keyword arguments as well.

```py
from typing import Callable, TypeVar

# A type variable that can represent any Callable type
C = TypeVar("C", bound=Callable)

# The input Callable type defines the output Callable type as well
def decorate(func: C) -> C:
    return func
```

---

If `decorate` can only work with callables that may take a string, adjust the `bound` accordingly.

```
# A type variable that can represent any Callable type that takes a string
C = TypeVar("C", bound=Callable[[str], None])
```

Notably, a callable taking a `str` *or using a default* still satisfies `Callable[[str], None]` since it can be called with a `str` argument.

Answer (score 1):

`Protocol` and `__call__` give a lot of (somewhat verbose) power when expressing function types

```
class Foo(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, some_str: str = 'Hello world') -> None:
        ...

def decorate(func: Foo) -> Foo:
    return func

@decorate
def do_something(some_str: str = 'Hello world') -> None:
    print(some_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_something()
```

Not sure how to satisfyingly avoid the "Hello World!" duplication.

Comment: Also worth noting that that actual default value in the protocol definition doesn't matter; it doesn't have to match the value used by `do_something`.

Comment: @chepner yes, I suppose that's right

Comment: Thanks! I solved my problem in this way except that I replaced `'Hello world'` with `...`. Using protocols is even more strict, and I like that for my application in mind. However, I accepted the other answer since I think that this better fits the question that I posted.

Comment: In the case someone wonders: Protocols strictly distinguish between arguments and keyword arguments. So if one wants a solution that works with and without default arguments, one can do something like follows: Define `Protocol` subtypes `DoSomethingWithoutDefault` (without `= ...`) and `DoSomethingWithDefault`, then define `DoSomething = Union[DoSomethingWithoutDefault, DoSomethingWithDefault]`, and finally use a type variable as suggested by @MisterMiyagi.